# "component is not a known element" - after moving a component to parent module

Tags: angular, typescript

In order to re-use a component, I'm trying to move a component from a module to its parent with no success (Multiple child modules are supposed to use it).

Originally, the child module had the following code inside (I want to move `MyDesiredComponent`):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng-click-outside';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import { MyDesiredComponent } from '../common/timeline/timeline.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ClickOutsideModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChildComponent,
    MyDesiredComponent
  ]

})

export class ChildModule   { }
```

I moved the declaration into a parent module, as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ChildModule } from './child/child.module';
import { DesiredComponent } from './common/desired/desired.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ChildModule
  ],
  declarations: [DesiredComponent],
  exports: [DesiredComponent]
})
export class ParentModule { }
```

After moving the component, the app fails to load, presenting the following error: `'desired-component' is not a known element`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is your code for bootstrapping the ParentModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be by "lazy loading" the component in a shared module, and import that inside your app.module.ts

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DesiredComponent } from '';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [DesiredComponent, LoadingComponent],
  exports: [DesiredComponent,
    CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterModule]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SharedModule } from '';
import { AppComponent } from '';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach. But one question why you are creating/calling forRoot method for Shared Module. Won't it work fine without it?

Comment: I import RouterModule inside SharedModule